# How to get matched pattern in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Here is the dataframe

```
entity=pd.DataFrame({'entity':[ 'freelancing is my job','my pill bottle','tuckaway tavern','80s font','talha','rnva stock','tied up','placester']})
kw=pd.DataFrame({'kw':[ 'is my','pill bottle','my tavern','talha']})
```

Here is how to find pattern

```
pattern = '|'.join(kw.kw.tolist())
entity[entity.entity.str.contains(pattern)]#partial match
```

Output

```
                  entity
0  freelancing is my job
1         my pill bottle
4                  talha
```

But what I want is to get matched patterns

```
kw
is my
pill bottle
talha
```

Is there a quick and efficient way to do this. Then I want to merge both entity and kw dataframe based on the matching

Answer (score 2):

How about `str.extract`:

```
entity.entity.str.extract(f'({pattern})')
```

Output:

```
             0
0        is my
1  pill bottle
2          NaN
3          NaN
4        talha
5          NaN
6          NaN
7          NaN
```

Comment: I tried this, `entity.entity.str.extract(pattern)` before but it give me this error. 
`ValueError: pattern contains no capture groups` So can you explain what is this `f` thing doing

Comment: Please see my answer again. What inside `extract` in my code is different from what you posted. I put the `pattern` inside a capture group `()`.